# select launguage popup cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

In this code I am checking if a cookie is set and running a code to pop up a flag selection. If the cookie is not set it will set the cookie once a flaf is checked. It works in chrome but wont work on firefox. I used the code from WC3. Can someone help me find the issue here. Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var languageSet = getCookie("setLanguage");
    if (languageSet != "" || languageSet != null) {
        return null;
    } else {
            jQuery.fancybox("#selectFlagDiv");
            setCookie("setLanguage", setLanguage, 365);
        }
}

</script>

<div id="selectFlagDiv" onload="checkCookie();" style="display:none;">
       <a href="https://bennhail.com/shop/?___store=arabic"> <img style="margin-bottom:18px;margin-top:18px;width:300px;height:180px;" src="1.gif" onclick="setLangStorage();" /></a>
       <a href="https://bennhail.com/shop/?___store=english"> <img style="margin-bottom:18px;margin-top:18px;width:300px;height:180px;" src="2.gif" onclick="setLangStorage();" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I propose to use localStorage not cookie

Comment: My client has another cookie set for the language so i need this to be in sync when his cookie is cleared. I cant see why its not working however

Comment: What is the error on firefox?

Comment: theres no error it just doesnt work